# Can I use Bootstrap Tooltips inside table cell?

Tags: html-table, css-tables

I'm trying to use [Twitter Bootstrap Tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) in table cell. Either this way:

```
<td><span rel="tooltip" title="Tooltip" data-delay="500">A<sub>p</sub></span></td>
```

or without a span:

```
<td rel="tooltip" title="Tooltip" data-delay="500">A<sub>p</sub></td>
```

Works just fine in both versions, but in each situation Netbeans warns me: "*Attribute `rel` not allowed on element `span`/`td` at this point.*".

What am I missing or doing wrong? Is it allowed to have tooltips in table cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rel` attribute is to identify the relationship between current document and the target link. So `rel` can be used in:

- tags link anchor,
- link tag which has stylesheet URL,

In your case, you have used for tooltip which is not a standard defined by W3C. Hence, NetBeans objects and throws a warning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and welcome to Stack Overflow. When giving answers, consider formatting them using Markdown (fixed) and consider upvoting question, if you find it enough interesting to place your answer (unspoken, but very welcome attitude here).

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Netbeans.  From what it is saying, as per HTML specification, you can not have tooltip on `span` and `td` tags.

However, if the target browsers support your attributes on `span`/`td` tags, you can use it. Moreover, you can prefix them using `data-` e.g. `data-rel`.

Comment: Nope, at least not in this case. Changing `rel` to `data-rel` causes Twitter Bootstrap Tooltips to not work. Text provided in `title` attribute is then displayed as standard browser tooltip, not Bootstrap one.

Comment: From the link I quote

>The required markup for a tooltip is only a **data** attribute and title on the HTML element you wish to have a tooltip. The generated markup of a tooltip is rather simple, though it does require a position (by default, set to top by the plugin).

can you edit your code to have `data-toggle="tooltip"` attribute and check?

Comment: I don't see any link in your answer (maybe it was removed during an edit?), so I don't know, what you are quoting. Anyway, changing `rel="tooltip"` to `data-toggle="tooltip"` for `<div>` element also didn't bring any solution -- tooltips are again displayed as simple, dully, browser-like tooltips.